# Concatenate two audios with different duration time

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I need to concatenate two audios, but I need to keep the size of the video with the size of the audio "backgroud.wav". I'm doing like this:

```
 $code1 = "ffmpeg -y -i voz.wav -i backround.wav -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 somnovo2.mp3";


system($code1);
```

But the result is the size of the audio "voz.wav" which would be 30 seconds. While "background.wav" is 3 minutes long. I need the output to have the time of "background.wav". How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `apad` filter before `amerge`

```
$code = 'ffmpeg -y -i voz.wav -i background.wav -filter_complex "[0]apad[a];[a][1]amerge[aout]" -map "[aout]" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3'

system($code);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it worked! However, you had to change single quotes to double quotes. I will put my solution here. Thank you very much :))

Comment: That's my fault sorry. Edited!

Answer (score 1):

As Anwsonwsymous answer, the final result looked like this:

```
    $code = "ffmpeg -y -i voz.wav -i background.wav -filter_complex \"[0]apad[a];[a][1]amerge[aout]\" -map \"[aout]\" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3";

$code1 = "ffmpeg -loop 1 -i result.jpg -i output.mp3 -shortest -acodec copy fim.mp4";



system($code);

system($code1);
```

The

> system($code);

merges the two audios into one, keeping the background audio repeating until the end.

End

> system($code2);

merges the finished audio with an image and converts it to .mp4 video with the duration of the background audio.

Comment: Please explain why the quotes had to be changed and why you run ffmpeg twice.